# Can you use an Xbox one console without internet?

Tags: xbox-one

I am planning on buying an xbox console,
but I have no internet connection.

Am I going to be able to make use of it offline?
out of box set-up will be done at a relatives house where there's a connection.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use your console offline. According to [this official page](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/networking/using-xbox-one-offline) by xbox.com, this is what you can and can't do:

> When your Xbox is offline you can:
>
> - Watch TV (though you need to be online for OneGuide listings)
> - Sign in to your profile (if you've signed in online before)
> - Change console settings (except for profile and family settings; content controls remain in place while offline)
> - Play games (provided you've set this as your home Xbox or have a game disc)
> - Save game clips and screenshots
> - Earn achievements (however, there's limited offline space for game captures and achievements, so you should go online every so often to sync them)
>
> Activities your Xbox must be online for include:
>
> - Playing games and apps that require the internet
> - Syncing game progress and playing saved games from a different Xbox
> - Using social features like friends, messages, and parties
> - Shopping for games, add-ons, movies, and so on
> - Updating games, apps, and your Xbox console

However, the page also specifies that:

> You must be online when you set up Xbox One for the first time. Without an internet connection, you can’t finish setup. After your Xbox has updated and you’ve added your profile, you can go offline.

On the page I linked you can find help on how to set up your Xbox to use it offline.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but the functionality is very limited, as most games of today require an on going connection of some kind. Also with the constant updates required by both the games and the console itself, it would be difficult for you to do much with the console. Also only some games can be played completely offline, so make sure you do your research.

Comment: This is not accurate and doesn't reflect my experience.

Comment: @Eric if that is the case then please leave your own answer.

Comment: Many single player games still require an online connection, so definately research each game you plan to buy ahead of time thoroughly as Parzival suggested. I was caught off guard with how many games I own that I couldn't play when internet was down. I hear it is same with ps4.

Answer (score 0):

Without an active internet connection, the Xbox One is basically useless - you cannot even connect to your own private network that doesn't even require internet...ie:  you have DLNA streaming content you want to watch but it won't see anything.   If you go to your Xbox One network settings and go offline, it shuts down the network interface so you are toast there.

Never had this problem with the Xbox 360 so Microsoft has pushed people into buying their Live service to use the console.

Comment: The other answers seem to contradict what you have stated.